# Importing XML into Access with an XSL transform

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-access-2013

I've seen a few other answers for similar answers, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. I have an attribute centric XML file that I need to import into Access, which will only accept element centric formatting. It seems like I need to do a transform with an XSL file, but I'm not clear how to do it. Since the data is proprietary, I've disguised it with a sci fi theme. What I need to do is turn the first code example into the same format as the second one:

```
<PLANETARY Protocol="Solar 1">
  <COLONIES>
        <COLONYDATA site="10001" planet="Mars">
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="RadiationDanger" value="Low" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="ApplicantColonists" value="11" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="AcceptedColonists" value="3" />
        </COLONYDATA>
        <COLONYDATA site="10002" planet="Mars">
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="RadiationDanger" value="Low" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="ApplicantColonists" value="7" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="AcceptedColonists" value="1" />
        </COLONYDATA>
        <COLONYDATA site="11019" planet="Titan">
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="RadiationDanger" value="Low" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="ApplicantColonists" value="22" />
            <RESOURCEDATA resource="AcceptedColonists" value="16" />
        </COLONYDATA>
    </COLONIES>
  </PLANETARY>


<Protocol>
Solar1
    <COLONIES>
        <COLONYDATA>
            <site>10001</site>
            <planet>Mars</planet>
            <RadiationDanger>Low</RadiationDanger>
            <ApplicantColonists>11</ApplicantColonists>
            <AcceptedColonists>3</AcceptedColonists>
        </COLONYDATA>
        <COLONYDATA>
            <site>10002</site>
            <planet>Mars</planet>
            <RadiationDanger>Low</RadiationDanger>
            <ApplicantColonists>7</ApplicantColonists>
            <AcceptedColonists>1</AcceptedColonists>
        </COLONYDATA>
        <COLONYDATA>
            <site>11019</site>
            <planet>Titan</planet>
            <RadiationDanger>Low</RadiationDanger>
            <ApplicantColonists>22</ApplicantColonists>
            <AcceptedColonists>16</AcceptedColonists>
        </COLONYDATA>
    </COLONIES>
</Protocol>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have to be careful with this, because if one of the resource attributes contains a string that is not a valid element name, you will get a fatal error.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Anything in particular I should look out for in terms of invalid strings?

Comment: From the spec: "*The first character of a Name MUST be a [NameStartChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar), and any other characters MUST be [NameChars](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar);*" -- [Short (unofficial) version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document#Requirements): Tag names cannot contain any of the characters `!"#$%&'()*+,/;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~`, nor a space character, and cannot start with `-`, `.`, or a numeric digit.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That explains why I was having trouble with trouble with the protocol name that had a space in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XSLT. `templates` matching `RESOURCEDATA` and `PLANETARY` are defined as per your transformation needs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*" >
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/PLANETARY">
    <Protocol>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Protocol"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </Protocol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RESOURCEDATA">
    <xsl:element name="{@resource}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The third template `<xsl:template match="/PLANETARY">` creates a `Protocol` element, adds `@Protocol` value, and applies templates to its nodes(i.e., in this case, applying templates to its child elements).

The fouth template `<xsl:template match="RESOURCEDATA">` creates an element with name as `@resource`'s value, and value from `@value`.

Coming to the first two templates, first one (`<xsl:template match="@*" >`) when applied to any attribute converts it into an element(element-centric).

And the second template, `<xsl:template match="@*" >` matches nodes(in your case elements), copy the tags, and apply templates for its attribtues and child elements(in a recursive way).

Comment: Superb! It works perfectly! Thank you! I thought seeing it applied to my own data would help me understand it better, but apparently not as well as I thought. The bottom half is more or less clear, but the second and third clusters are more mysterious. I'll see what I can google before bothering you further.

Comment: Lingamurthy, that is helpful. Thank you again. I also found this tool online that lets you see what the result of the XSLT transform is by pasting it and the XML code in; this is helping me understand what you did as well: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

I'm sorry I don't yet have enough rep to vote you up, but I very much appreciate this.

Comment: Lingamurthy, is it possible to get the protocol name ("Solar1" in the example) to repeat as an element so it shows up as a column in the resulting table?

Comment: Everything is possible.. The question isn't much clear but looks easier.. Please ask a new question with your request XML, expected output and your tried XSLT and someone will sure help you out..